# How to automatically compare current windows root certificate store against latest root certificates?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, certutil

I do have a provider that complains the trusted root certificates on our several windows server systems (2008, 2012, 2016, 2019) are outdated.
I was not able to prove the opposite. For sure "Turn off Automatic Certificate Update" is not configured on any of those systems and thus the root storage should be updated.

**First question:**
Anyway, is there a **simple automated way** (or even a slick tool) that would **compare** the actual installed trusted root certificates on a windows system against the newest trusted root on the internet?

I could

- download the latest root certificates with "certutil -generateSSTFromWU WURoots.sst"
- do some magic with the PowerShell *CERT* commands (see "Get-Command *CERT*")
- do compare serial numbers, thumbprint, etc..

Yet, I am not really a programmer.

Perhaps there is a tool around which would do what I'd need?

**Second question:**
Besides comparing, is there a simple way to force the root certificates to be **updated**?
Yes, I could go the way with

- certutil -generateSSTFromWU WURoots.sst
- select the certificates I need and export it into an own .sst file
- use Import-Certificate (or distribute over GPO)

There is surely a less complicated and more automated way?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 3):

By default, root certificates are automatically updated through [Windows Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749331(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_Procedures).

You may have this feature disabled in your environment through GPO? You can check if the key below has been set, but it does not exist by default:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\AuthRoot -Name DisableRootAutoUpdate
```

It also requires certain updates for 2008/2012 like [KB3004394](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-urgent-trusted-root-updates-for-windows-root-certificate-program-in-windows-a4ac4d6c-7c62-3b6e-dfd2-377982bf3ea5), so make sure you're up to date in general.

---

I don't recommend managing root certs manually, but you can easily view the existing certs using the [Certificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/About/about_Certificate_Provider) provider like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\CA\
```

And maybe you want to compare your local certificates to a remote machine:

```
# Get the list of local root/CA certificates
$localCerts = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\CA\)+(Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\)

# Compare to the same certificates on a remote server
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Server01' -ScriptBlock {
  $remoteCerts = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\CA\)+(Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\)
  Compare-Object $using:localCerts $remoteCerts -Property thumbprint -PassThru
}

# Display certificates that don't match
$result | select SideIndicator,Thumbprint,FriendlyName,Subject
```

Here's an example comparing between win10 and Server 2016. You can see one of the differences is my local machine has a TPM module it trusts:

```
SideIndicator Thumbprint                               Subject                                                                                          
------------- ----------                               -------                                                                                          
=>            DE28F4A4FFE5B92FA3C503D1A349A7F9962A8212 CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US                                                     
<=            D4FFDB19BA590FFFAA34DB5F4B568706A2978436 CN=Microsoft TPM Root Certificate Authority 2014, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washin...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [SigCheck](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) for this.

```
 sigcheck.exe -tv
```

it lists certificates not rooted in the Microsoft Certificate Trust list.

I use this from a PowerShell [script](https://hahndorf.eu/blog/UseOnlyValidCAs.html) to alert me about untrusted certificates.